# Instanciate class A with values from instantiated class B when A and B inherit from same class (C#)

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have the following

```cs
public class A{
    
     public string foo {get;set;}
     public string bar {get;set;}
     public int baz {get;set;}
    
}


public class B:A
{
    public string wuz {get;set;}
}

public class C:A
{

    public int yuh {get;set;}
}
```

If I then make an instance of `B`

```cs
var b = new B(){wuz="wow",foo="hello",bar="wordl",baz=18};
```

and later on I want to use those values of `B` in `C`, then I have to manually write

```cs
c = new C(){yuh=20, foo = b.foo, bar = b.bar, baz=b.baz};
```

isn't there a way to make `c` take the already instantiated values from `B` in a dynamic way, and parse them onto `C`? In this example it is easy to to, but say I have 500 properties then it's not feasible

(I'm fairly new to .NET thus there might be a typo/syntax error in the codeexample above, but I think the problem should be rather clear)

Comment: You could add a constructor to `C` which takes an instance of `B` and then encapsulate all those property settings in that constructor.

Comment: But then in the constructor I still have to write all properties explicit. I wan't to avoid that

Comment: Then it sounds like you're looking for tools like Automapper.

Comment: You could also use reflection (but I guess Automapper will do something similar)

Comment: Adding the new constructor is something that has to be done once, assigning each property (as in your question) has to be done every time. Also, if you really have 500 Properties on a class I'd take a really hard look at how to reduce that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a constructor to `C` that takes an instance of `A` (or if you really want to do that `B`). Would look something like this:

```cs
public class C:A
{
    public C() {}
    public C(A other)
    {
        this.foo = other.foo;
        ...
    }
    public int yuh {get;set;}
}
```

If you also want the same capability in `B`, you might want to add this kind of constructor to `A`, and call it from `C`:

```cs
public class A{
    public A(){}
    public A(A other)
    {
        this.foo = other.foo;
        ...
    }

    public string foo {get;set;}
    public string bar {get;set;}
    public int baz {get;set;}
    
}

public class C:A
{
    public C(){}
    public C(A other) : base(other) {}

    public int yuh {get;set;}
}
```

In either case you can now create a new instance of `C`like this:

```cs
c = new C(b){ yuh = 20};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You need to write method that will take B instance and sets all properties with reflection.

```
public C CreateCFromB(B bInstance)
{
   var cInstance = new C();
   foreach (var property in typeof(B).GetProperties())
   {
        var propertyValue = property.GetValue(bInstance, null);
        property.SetValue(cInstance, propertyValue);
   }
   return cInstance;
}
```

You can take more generalized approach with generic types.

```
public TWhat CreateFrom<TFrom, TWhat>(TFrom tFromInstance)
    where TWhat : TFrom, new()
{
    var tWhatInstance = new TWhat();
    foreach (var property in typeof(TFrom).GetProperties())
    {
        var propertyValue = property.GetValue(tFromInstance, null);
        property.SetValue(tWhatInstance, propertyValue);
    }
  
    return tWhatInstance;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to make this method static, and cast the bInstance to `A`, or take an instance of A in the first place.